# google maps, adding more markers to array and body

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

how would I go about adding additional markers to this set up?  There are currently three and I've been messing around with it, but I'm not sure how to continue adding markers to it

I've been trying things on this JS Bin as well http://jsbin.com/agemuw/2/edit but haven't got it working

JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var locations = [
[
"850 Boylston Street",
"Chestnut Hill, MA 02467",
"42.326435",
"-71.149499"
],
[
"Subway Brookline Village",
"Green Line, D",
"42.33279",
"-71.11630"
],
[
"Shuttle Brookline Village",
"10 Brookline Place",
"42.33262",
"-71.116439"
]
];

gmarkers = [];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 16,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.326435, -71.149499),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


function createMarker(latlng, html) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
return marker;
}

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
/*    alert("location:"+
      locations[i][0]+":"+locations[i][2]+","+locations[i][3]);
*/
gmarkers[locations[i][0]]=
createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]), locations[i][0]    
+ "<br>" + locations[i][1]);
}

/*                                                    
$(function() {
$('#locations h3 a').each(function() { 
    $(this).on('click', function() { 
        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');    
    })    
  });    
});

*/
});//]]>
```

html:

```
<body>      
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <div id="locations">
        <h3><a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers['850 Boylston  
Street'],'click');">850 Boylston Street</a></h3>
        <p>Arbitrary content about 1</p>

        <h3><a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers['Subway Brookline 
Village'],'click');">Brookline Village T Stop</a></h3>
        <p>Arbitrary content about 2</p>

        <h3><a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers['Shuttle Brookline 
Village'],'click');">Shuttle - 10 Brookline Place</a></h3>
        <p>Arbitrary content about 3</p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a Javascript error

after the 3rd location you are missing a comma `,` after the square bracket `]`

```
///....snip
"10 Brookline Place",
"42.33262",
"-71.116439"
], //right here
[
"Subway Chestnut Hill",
"Green Line, D",
///...snip
```

EDIT

adding custom markers to the map
Add the icon property like below - easy way is to just put a url in - hard way if you want to define shadows and anchor points is to build one - see the Google Maps API for the in depth stuff

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon : "http://urlofmymarker.png", //comma is important
    position: latlng,
    map: map
});
```

Comment: just keep adding the locations (not questions) in the correct format and all should be good :-)

Comment: hey quick question, is there an easy way to add a custom marker into this set up easily?

Comment: last question, is it possible to set it up so I could use different custom markers for different places?  Thanks a lot for helping me.